# Tuprolog and defining infix operators

Tags: java, prolog, tuprolog

So I have some prolog...

```
cobrakai$more operator.pl 
be(a,c).
:-op(35,xfx,be).



+=(a,c).
:-op(35,xfx,+=).
cobrakai$
```

Which defines some infix operators. I run it using SWI prolog and get the following (perfectly expected) results

```
?- halt.
cobrakai$swipl -s operator.pl 
% library(swi_hooks) compiled into pce_swi_hooks 0.00 sec, 3,992 bytes
% /Users/josephreddington/Documents/workspace/com.plancomps.prolog.helloworld/operator.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 992 bytes
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 5.10.5)
Copyright (c) 1990-2011 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- be(a,c).
true.

?- a be c.
true.

?- +=(a,c).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: (+=)/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
?- halt.
cobrakai$swipl -s operator.pl 
% library(swi_hooks) compiled into pce_swi_hooks 0.00 sec, 3,992 bytes
% /Users/josephreddington/Documents/workspace/com.plancomps.prolog.helloworld/operator.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 1,280 bytes
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 5.10.5)
Copyright (c) 1990-2011 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- be(a,c).
true.

?- a be c.
true.

?- +=(a,c).
true.

?- a += c.
true.

?- halt.
```

However, when I use Tuprolog to process the same file from Java (using the following code)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import alice.tuprolog.Prolog;
import alice.tuprolog.SolveInfo;
import alice.tuprolog.Theory;

public class Testinfixoperatorconstruction {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Prolog engine = new Prolog();
        engine.loadLibrary("alice.tuprolog.lib.DCGLibrary");
        engine.addTheory(new Theory(readFile("/Users/josephreddington/Documents/workspace/com.plancomps.prolog.helloworld/operator.pl")));
        SolveInfo info = engine.solve("be(a,c).");
        System.out.println(info.getSolution());
        info = engine.solve("a be c.");
        System.out.println(info.getSolution());
    }

    private static String readFile(String file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(ls);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

The prolog file does not parse - failing on the '+=' token.

```
Exception in thread "main" alice.tuprolog.InvalidTheoryException: Unexpected token '+='
    at alice.tuprolog.TheoryManager.consult(TheoryManager.java:193)
    at alice.tuprolog.Prolog.addTheory(Prolog.java:242)
    at Testinfixoperatorconstruction.main(Testinfixoperatorconstruction.java:14)
```

We can try a slightly different approach, adding the operator directly in the java code with...

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Prolog engine = new Prolog();
    engine.loadLibrary("alice.tuprolog.lib.DCGLibrary");

```
engine.getOperatorManager().opNew("be", "xfx", 35);
engine.getOperatorManager().opNew("+=", "xfx", 35);
engine.addTheory(new Theory(
        readFile("/Users/josephreddington/Documents/workspace/com.plancomps.prolog.helloworld/operator2.pl")));
SolveInfo info = engine.solve("be(a,c).");
System.out.println(info.getSolution());
info = engine.solve("a be c.");
System.out.println(info.getSolution());
```

}

but we get the same error... :(

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? (and solutions would also be welcome).

Comment: Perhaps Tuprolog does not support that, note it seems to have an [operator management class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/it.unibo.alice.tuprolog/tuprolog/2.1.1/alice/tuprolog/OperatorManager.java#OperatorManager).  That error was a lexical (tokenizer) error, so it was obviously not expecting the new token, and had not registered it with its lexer.

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog could be too much permissive while parsing directives. Try enclosing operators between parenthesis:

```
:-op(35,xfx,(+=)).
```

*edit* I tried using 2p.jar, that allowed me to spot the problem. Need to quote operator' atom:

```
:-op(35,xfx, '+=').

X += Y.
p :- a += b.
```

interactive 2p console accepts this syntax. Note that 2p.jar by default load tuprolog *libraries*

Comment: It's a nice idea, and thank you for the answer, but I'm afraid it didn't help :(

Comment: SWI is not "too much permissive" here. Neither quotes nor brackets are needed. `:- op(35, xfx, +=).` is valid ISO Prolog syntax.